# Missing edit icon on Galaxy S launcher

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, launcher

I am trying to change the 4 icons that are along the bottom of the screen on my Samsung Galaxy S. All the answers I have looked at say 'press menu and then select edit', but I don't have an edit button. When I press <kbd>Menu</kbd> I see:

- All programs
- Add to home screen
- Wallpaper
- Search
- Notifications
- Settings

Where is the edit button?

Comment: Edit what? What app(s) are you talking about?

Comment: If you're talking about launcher... some launchers have Edit in there to add more screens, remove screens... but then again the context of question is not clear so please clarify!

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to change the 4 icons that are along the bottom of the screen, all the answers I have looked at say 'press menu and then select edit' I don't have edit only the ones I have mentioned. Don't know where it is. Thanks

Comment: @user26978 it's quite a while since I owned a Galaxy S, but I seem to remember that you could just long-press on the icons on the bottom row, and then drag them in or out. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to Menu, press view type and select customizable grid. Now you can see an edit button as mentioned by several posts

Comment: There is no such option when you press menu from the home screen. You have to go to 'Applications' first, and then press menu! Also note that this onlyt works in the Samsung stock TouchWiz launcher.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It looks like I will have to make do with the icons that are there. Doesn't look like they can be changed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Long press the icons and you will be able to move or remove them.